# Issue to deploy a wordpress website through ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rds

I follow [this](https://www.otreva.com/blog/deploying-wordpress-amazon-web-services-aws-ec2-rds-via-elasticbeanstalk/) and [this](http://yourstory.com/2012/05/tutorial-deploying-wordpress-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-and-amazon-rds-part-33/) to create a wordpress website through AWS ElasticBeanstalk.

What I did:

1. Create a wordpress site in localhost
2. Create an app in ElasticBeanstalk with RDS
3. Export database locally and import to RDS
4. Initialize git in wordpress folder locally
5. Download the ElasticBeanstalk Command line tool and add it to wordpress folder
6. Run git aws.config
7. Run git aws.push

It works well until the step 7. I got the following error message:

> Updating the AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment
>   mywordpress-env... Error: Failed to get the Amazon S3 bucket
>   name

Can anybody explain what this mean? And how to solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Attach User Policy(Power user access) in IAM solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had such problem today, when My Ubuntu laptop didn't change the time automatically, so  there was one-hour time difference in comparison to real time:).

I hope you solved the problem before my answer :)